# type mismatch flink graph community

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, gelly

I am trying to execute a very simple code for community detection but it returns an error:

```
import org.apache.flink.graph.library.CommunityDetection
import org.apache.flink.graph._
import org.apache.flink.graph.scala.Graph
import java.lang.Long
import java.lang.Double
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val vertices = Seq(new Vertex[Long, String](1L, "foo"), new Vertex[Long, String](2L, "bar"))
val edges = Seq(new Edge[Long, String](1L, 2L, "foobar"))

val graph = Graph.fromCollection(vertices, edges, env)
val updatedGraph = graph.mapVertices(v => v.getValue + 1)
val resultGraph = graph.run(new CommunityDetection[Long](30, 0.5))


                            ^
```

Comment: Error:(30, 33) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.flink.graph.library.CommunityDetection[Long]
 required: org.apache.flink.graph.GraphAlgorithm[Long,String,String,?]
    val resultGraph = graph.run(new CommunityDetection[Long](30, 0.5))

Answer (score 0):

The `CommunityDetection` algorithm expects a `Graph` with `Long` Ids and vertex values and `Double` edge weights. In your code, you define `String` values for the vertices and the edges.
Please, look [at the Gelly documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/batch/libs/gelly.html#community-detection) for more detailed usage information.

Comment: I am using the following code and still get an exception. Could you give an example of a working code, please? Thank you.    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val vertices = Seq(new Vertex[Long, Double](1L, 0.1), new Vertex[Long, Double](2L, 0.4))
    val edges = Seq(new Edge[Long, Double](1L, 2L, 0.5))

    val graph = Graph.fromCollection(vertices, edges, env)

Comment: The problem is that you are using `Double` vertex values. Both vertex ids and values have to be `Long`. Try replacing your vertex creation with e.g. 

`val vertices = Seq(new Vertex[Long, Long](1L, 1L), new Vertex[Long, Long](2L, 4L))`.